# What would be the most efficient way to add these text files to the code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have been trying to create a font type app that changes how the original text looks using emoji styles and uni-code. To create these "fonts" all the letters need to be attached to every key from A-Z to apply the desired effect. There is a few ways to do this i have seen. in a .txt format and a .plist format. Im using a .plist to link every single keyboard letter with a new letter which includes both lower case and capitol letters. This method would just take forever and is very tedious, so i was wondering if there is an easier way. There are apps that have over 100 fonts, so if you did the math, that's just a very long time to just copy/paste every letter 52 times for every font. Please help with any suggestions. Thank you! you will save me lots of time!

Example app that does what mine will do: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/better-fonts-free-cool-new/id735011588?mt=8

example of changing every letter and my setup: [image: .plist of changing the letter characters]

Comment: Sorry, but this is confusing (to me at least). Can you clarify (maybe show an example) what you are trying to generate? Perhaps you should include an example in your question.

Comment: When an app includes a custom font, it is usually by including a .ttf or .otf file. You should look into that!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend finding the font you want on the in internet and then importing it into your project like a .ttf file. Then you can just change the text to this specific font... simple. If you still needed some fonts that use emojis or whatever and you can not find the font on the internet, you are just going to have hunker down and do the plist files. :)